# Differentiability of $\sum x^j$

Tags: derivatives

Prove that $\sum x^j$ is differentiable on (-1,1), and $$\frac{d}{dx} \sum x^j = \sum (j+1) x^j$$

I am able to prove that $\sum x^j$ converges uniformly to $\frac{1}{1+x}$. However, how do I get this derivative? It doesn't seem to follow traditional derivative rules.

Comment: I don't know how formal of a proof you want, but as far as getting the derivative from typical rules: $$\sum_{j\ge0}(j)x^{j-1} = \sum_{j\ge1}(j)x^{j-1} = \sum_{j\ge0}(j+1)x^{j}$$

Comment: But how does this derivative come by differentiating $\sum x^j$?

Comment: The derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives.  This extends to series as well.

Comment: @kiwifruit since a serie converges absolutely on its open domain of convergence, you can make the limit that comes from the derivative and the one that comes from the infinite sum commute to show that the derivatives of the infinite sum is the infinite sum of the derivative of each term.

Comment: @kiwi Sorry, I misled you, its absolutely convergent on any intervals $(a,b)$ with $-1 < a < b < 1$ but not on the whole $(-1,1)$. However, this is sufficient to show our claim on derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does follow the traditional derivative rules.
But we need to treat the case $j=0$ separately, since the traditional rule for $x^j$ does not apply to it.
$$\frac d {dx} \sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j = \frac d {dx}\left(x^0 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty x^j\right)
= \frac d {dx}\left(1 + \sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{j+1}\right) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)x^{j}$$

Comment: Could you clarify why the traditional derivative rules don't apply to j=0?

Comment: According to the traditional rule we would have $\frac d {dx} x^0 = 0 \cdot x^{-1}$, but this is undefined for $x=0$.